# Does Google App Engine support multiprocessing via python, and does the DB support multiple writes in localhost?

Tags: google-app-engine, multiprocessing, google-cloud-datastore

Regarding a production environment, I would like to know if the python standard environment (2.7) at Google App Engine supports code with multiprocessing and pooling? Using Google´s datastore. Or should Map Reduce be used instead?

And regarding development environment in a localhost, also I would like to know, how to avoid a database lock when writing to the same database from processes started from different shell terminals?

Thanks

Comment: Normally you would use task queues for this kind of thing. And the production datastore is accessed entirely over RPC, so the question of locking does not arise.

Comment: I don't think the python multiprocessing is allowed on [the standard environment sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_The_sandbox): `An App Engine application cannot... make other kinds of system calls`

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [this post on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/D6z_WoLsBH8/WD4A4rHFBwAJ), where it is confirmed that multiprocessing is not available in Google App Engine (GAE) Standard environment, but you can implement it in [GAE Flexible.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#recommended_gunicorn_configuration) You might also be interested in [this post about parallel execution in GAE](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/10/efficient-use-of-asynchronous-operations-in-Google-App-Engine.html), and Tasklets in particular with a Cloud Datastore example.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding database lock:

Updates are actually done within a datastore transaction and NDB by default will retry the operation three times before failing altogether. It is recommended you only update an entity group once per second at the most.  If you are seeing database locks, then you're probably doing something wrong.  We implemented a version of the "fork-join queue" described by Brett Slatkin back in 2010 data pipelines talk, which is a method of "joining" many updates to the same entity such that they can all be applied at once at a controlled rate:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSDC_TU7rtc&feature=youtu.be&t=33m37s

also, see the discussion going on here:
[How to deal with eventual consistency in fork-join-queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914036/how-to-deal-with-eventual-consistency-in-fork-join-queue)