# Running multiple functions in parallel in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, multiprocessing

i'm trying to run multiple functions in parallel on my Google App Engine. For now, i'm using multiprocessing but it doesn't seem to work as it doesn't seem to lead anywhere whenever i run the following through an API call:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
result_objs = []
with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
    df1 = pool.apply_async(function1, (input_postcode, input_category1))
    df2 = pool.apply_async(function2, (input_postcode, input_category2))
    df3 = pool.apply_async(function3, (input_postcode, input_category3))
    result_objs.append(df1)
    result_objs.append(df2)
    result_objs.append(df3)
    results = [result.get() for result in result_objs]
```

Is it because GAE has only 1 CPU? Is it because multiprocessing library doesn't work on GAE?
Does Google offer an equivalent library for multiprocessing?
I've seen the following google library, but not too sure how this would be applied in my case?

```py
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
```

Answer (score 0):

A single CPU does not mean that it can only handle one process. The CPU in question is a virtual CPU anyway.

There's some resources that imply that multiproccessing is available on Flexible but not on Standard, as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51724019/9267296). Gunicorn is used to serve several instances of your app, each in it's separate process on a single GAE instance, so multiprocessing does work, at least on the GAE instance level. I'm not 100% sure if it does on each Gunicorn app instance...

What do your actual GAE logs say?

Which *flavor* of GAE are you running? Flex or Standard?

Comment: Yes it's flexible
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 220
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.6